# Flutter PageRoute / PageRouteBuilder buildTransitions building on every frame

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-routes

Flutter's extendable PageRoute class (also implemented by PageRouteBuilder) has two primary methods for the page content, `buildPage` for the primary content and `buildTansitions` to wrap the content in one or more transition widgets.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageRoute-class.html

I have noticed some slightly sluggish transitions and slow frames. Having attempted to track this I have found that `buildPage` builds as one would expect whilst `buildTransitions` is building on every single frame as if it was the `builder` of an `AnimatedBuilder` widget.

This does not appear to be the intended behaviour according to the docs and `buildTransitions` should only rebuild when the Route's state changes. I have disabled all custom inherited widgets and hero animations but cannot determine why it is building on every frame.

Am I missing something here? What could be causing this?

```
 class TestFadeRoute<T> extends PageRoute<T> {
   TestFadeRoute(TestFadePage<T> page);
    
   TestFadePage<T> get _page => settings as TestFadePage<T>;
    
   @overrides // etc.. etc..
    
    buildPage(context, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
      print('buildPageDidBuild'); 
      // debug message (does so once or when ModalRoute is modified)

      return Semantics(
        scopesRoute: true,
        explicitChildNodes: true,
        child: _page.child,
        );
     }
    
     buildTransitions(context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
       print('buildTransitionsDidBuild');
       // debug message (doing so on every frame of the animation)

       return FadeTransition(
         opacity: animation,
         child: child,
       );
     }
  }
```

Assuming that this is not intended behavior:

1. What could be causing this rebuild on every frame
2. Is there a way to determine if and when the Route's state has been changed.

The only work around I have found is to ignore buildTransitions and use ModalRoute of context inside the Widget passed to buildPage. But if this was the way to go about it, then why would buildTransitions exist in the first place?

Comment: see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f72efea43c3013323d1b95cff571f3c1caa37583/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart#L919 and line #922

Comment: @pskink Ah, so it is intended behaviour. Does this have any effect on performance? Would it be more performant for example to use the animation directly on Widgets instead of using a transition Widget? For example instead of doing a SizeTransition, use the animation.value to directly affect the dimensions of a SizedBox? Thanks,

Comment: sure, you can do that but I wouldn't expect any performance improvements

Comment: Marvellous, thanks

Comment: @pskink There were in fact performance improvements from maintaining the existing transition widgets and adding a further animated builder where appropriate. Thanks for your help, R

Comment: It seems to be to do with detecting use gestures but for the avoidance of any confusion in my last comment, I am saying that despite their animated builder meaning buildTransitions builds on every frame, I still get improvements if I use Transition Widgets and/or further AnimationBuilders than taking advantage of the fact buildTransitions is already building on every frame.

Comment: i see, btw if you want to avoid any rebuilds but still want your widgets to be animated in some way you can try `CustomMultiChildLayout` or `Flow` widgets where all the position / size changes are done in the custom "delegate" classes, few days ago I even made a `Stack` like widget that allows to move the children without rebuilding them: https://gist.github.com/pskink/10c8fd372113f0b36570db96d58d818e#file-flow_stack-dart-L20 (example starts from line #174)